# SugarCRM Rest API: Get Documents from Contracts

Tags: sugarcrm

Sugar CRM Rest API:
http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.5/70_API/Web_Services/20_Examples/v10/module_record_link_link_GET/

I am trying to get list of documents which belongs to specific contract using this api call like this

```
call(SugarCRM Url + '/Contracts/' + contract.id +'/link/documents','GET')
```

But I get

> {
>       "error": "not_found",
>       "error_message": "Could not find a relationship named: documents" }

But when I log in to Sugar CRM I am able to find the list of documents from Specific Contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link name between Contracts module and Documents module is **contracts_documents**

It will work for this URL: (*rest/v10/Contracts/<**ContractId**>/link/contracts_documents*)

Comment: Thanks Saad.It is really 'contracts_documents'

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using 
rest/v10/Contracts/029e901b-6118-460f-b8d9-37682c84d970/link/contracts_documents

It was the bug in sugarcrm and we should change it from link/documents to link/contracts_documents